# Where is Steady Hand McDuff?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I can't find Steady Hand McDuff. I have not looked in Iron Keep because I don't know where it is ether.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

He is in Lost Bastille. Not so far from entrance via flying bird - there are several dogs and barrel near stairs in that area.

> You can either found Bastille Key to open the door or push the barrel down the stairs and then detonate it (via torch or firebomb or flame enchanted weapon).

See also [this wiki page](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/steady-hand-mcduff).